# Using a layout with an activity

Tags: android, android-layout

So I just started playing around with android and I'm trying to see what things I can do. I was following the very first android tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html and at the very end, you programmatically define a TextView. I wanted to change this to be defined in a new layout, so I wrote this (it is named display_message.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And in the DisplayMessage class, I changed it to this:

```
public class DisplayMessage extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_message);

        // Get message from intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(FirstActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Get the text view
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText(message);
    }

}
```

However, Eclipse says that it doesn't know what `R.layout.display_message` is, nor does it know what `R.id.text_view` is. Is there somewhere else I need to define them or something? Where did I mess up?

Comment: Try cleaning the project. Eclipse sometimes has problems with refreshing the R.java file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems correct but be sure that the R class imported is the correct one.
Sometimes Eclipse imports android.R but the R file you need to import is your.package.name.R